# How do I import components into QtQuickDesigner?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt6, qtquick-designer

I am trying to learn Qt version 6, and I'm at a point where my book has me importing QtQuick Controls. The book says to click on the "Imports tab" in the Library pane, and shows a screenshot containing the tab. (Virtually every web source I've been able to find says the same thing, with a similar screenshot.)

Unfortunately, my installation of Qt-Creator, version 4.15.1, installed with Qt 6, does not have an Imports tab on the library pane. This is what my Library pane looks like:
[image: Screenshot of Library pane]

Yes, it appears that the controls have been imported, but I didn't do it through the UI, it happened during an experiment. What got the controls imported was:

1. I hand-edited the `.ui.qml` file to add the line

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
```

2. I built the project

This resulted in the QtQuick controls appearing in the Library pane.

Surely this is not the normal way of importing controls, is it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want **Qt Design Studio** to **import** modules for you **from the UI**.

Simply click here then:

[image]

Also, if your project was made with **Qt6**, there's no need to add the version in the import statement.

*I hope I was of any help :)*

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would indeed like to import modules through the UI. The mechanism laid out in the book I was using clearly does not work since there is no "Imports" tab in the UI. Unfortunately clicking on the plus sign you reference simply results in a components window that is empty except for the text __Select a Module to Add__, There are no listed modules from which to select.